# Different domain for different store view (language)

Tags: store-view, language, hreflang

Is it possible to have different views of my site (for languages / currencies) hosted off different domains

for example:

www.myshop.co.uk - English (GBP) version of the site
www.myshop.ie - English (EUR) (Irelenad) Version of the site
www.myshop.fr - French (EUR) Version of the site

I would use hreflang attribute on each page to denote languages etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. Given that you already setup your stores, `http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work.`

Just change the setting in:

```
   Admin > System > Configuration > Web >
```

Here you need to change the Current Configuration Scope to your Specific Website > 
    (Change the Base URL)